# Using two methods that create 2d Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I'm setting up a game board. Grid is the actual board with characters, and gameBoard is what's shown to the user. Both methods use the same 2 variables to create the arrays, except the variables are user inputs, and when I compile I am asked twice to enter the RxC.

How can I run both grid and game board, without having to call new Grid() again?

```
public class Controller 
{
    public void start()
    {
        String result = "";

        Grid grid = new Grid();
        grid.addMines();
        grid.update();
        View view = new View();

        Grid gameBoard = new Grid();
        result = gameBoard.toString();
        view.display(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try `Grid gameBoard = grid;`? Might be worthwhile to add your Grid class if issue is your arrays.

Comment: Why do you need two `Grid`s in the first place? why not just display the `grid`?

Comment: Im sorry that is correct, my brain was freezing for some reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confusion between naming object in Controller class, Solution is

```
String result = "";

        Grid grid = new Grid();
        grid.addMines();
        grid.update();
        grid.gameBoard();
        View view = new View();


        result = grid.toString();
        view.display(result);
```